# Move static site to WordPress

Tags: static-website

I want to move my website https://mysushi.ph/ to a simpler platform like WordPress so I can make small changes myself and don't be dependant on developers (e.g. title meta changes for SEO, posting blogs) the problem is I don't have a clue how to do, this can someone help me understand the process.

Comment: You need to be dependent on a developer to do so. This is too broad to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many sites that can help you become more familiar with how WordPress works. The WPBeginner site (search for it) is one of them. There are tons of end-user-level tutorials. You don't have to be a developer to use WordPress. You can use the default theme to get started. Or look for a theme that might be to your needs - there are tons of free ones.

There are tutorials for developing themes, but you don't need those (for now). And you don't need to know programming to create a site. Tons of plugins are available for you to find one that meets a specific need.

This place is for developer-type questions. And the more details you can provide on what you are asking will give you better answers.

For now, ask the googles/bings/ducks for some beginning WordPress tutorials. That should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your positive response rick I guess I have to make my self familiar to WordPress and websites and see where it takes me

Comment: Glad to help. Can be fun, in a geeky sort of way. 
(and clicking the checkmark to indicate a correct answer is something that is encouraged and appreciated around here)

Comment: haha thanks for your help rick i appreciate it!